# Show Custom Value in SQL Server Table Rows Based On Case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show custom value in table rows based on condition/case

For example:

```
SELECT 
    A.USERID, A.FNAME, A.LNAME, A.DISGN, A.DEPT, A.EMAIL, A.CONAM, 
    A.TELNO, A.ACTI, B.PLANTDESC,
    CASE
       WHEN ACTI = 'X' THEN 'Active' 
       WHEN ACTI = ' ' THEN 'In active'  
    END AS 'STATUS' 
FROM 
    USRM AS A
```

By using this we get separate temporary column with status:

```
4675    Paul K  NULL    PURCHASE-ENG    NULL    HETERO  NULL    X   Hetero Drugs Limited  Corp.Off  Active
```

But is it possible to get custom values ("Active"/"In Active") under `A.ACTI` column instead of X?

Comment: You Must **NOT** Uppercase Each And Every Word In English ....

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep "X",' ' values in the A.ACTI column, you can create a view. that view can be act as table if you want to read it. If you want to update/insert value use INSTEAD OF TRIGGER in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query:

```
SELECT A.USERID
,A.FNAME
,A.LNAME
,A.DISGN
,A.DEPT
,A.EMAIL
,A.CONAM
,A.TELNO
,CASE 
    WHEN ACTI = 'X'
        THEN 'Active'
    WHEN ACTI = ' '
        THEN 'In active' 
 END AS ACTI
,B.PLANTDESC
,CASE 
    WHEN ACTI = 'X'
        THEN 'Active'
    WHEN ACTI = ' '
        THEN 'In active'
    END AS 'STATUS' FROM USRM AS A
FROM USRM AS A
```

But if you want to to make in permanent in table then you've to update that value

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `case when` condition again instead of 'A.ACTI' to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this. Keep in mind: your data may be like 'X ', ' X', '  ' (two spaces). And, in these cases we have some problems. And, you do not handled cases, when your data looks like "F". This may be handled with ELSE

```
select 
        [userid]    =   [a].[userid]
    ,   [fname]     =   [a].[fname]
    ,   [lname]     =   [a].[lname]
    ,   [disgn]     =   [a].[disgn]
    ,   [dept]      =   [a].[dept]
    ,   [email]     =   [a].[email]
    ,   [conam]     =   [a].[conam]
    ,   [telno]     =   [a].[telno]
    ,   [acti]      =   [a].[acti]
    ,   [plantdesc] =   [b].[plantdesc]
    ,   [status]    =   case lower(ltrim(rtrim([a].[acti])))
                            when 'x' then 'Active'
                            when space(0) then 'In active'
                            else 'Unhandled case'
                        end
from 
    [usrm] as [a];
```